# How can I overlay 2 binary images to save the white color on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, image-processing, graphics, imagemagick, image-segmentation

Imagine there're two the same binary images (all pixels are black). And then you take the 1st image and make some of the pixels white (e.g., points `(10,10)` and `(11, 11)`) and do the same operation for point `(5, 4)` of the 2nd image and save the result images as `image1.png` and `image2.png`.

The goal is to create the third image (`result.png`) that will have every pixel as black but 3 points: `(5, 4)`, `(10,10)`, and `(11,11)` that should be white. How can I do this operation in Ubuntu automatically?

[composite](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/composite-im6.1.html) looks like a good command to look into. I tried to use `composite -blend` and then didn't manage to find the correct command to save the white color.

Comment: The title actually doesn’t say it all. What white color? How should they be overlayed? And if you already have a command in mind, what did you try with it and what didn’t work? And is this about programming or just using general commands? If the latter, it should be, for example, in Super User and not here.

Comment: please read [ask]

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I'm sorry, added the details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given `image1.png` with white points @ 10,10 & 11,11

```
convert -size 100x100 xc:black -fill white -draw 'point 10, 10' -draw 'point 11,11' image1.png
```

[image: image1]

And `image2.png` with white points @ 5,4

```
convert -size 100x100 xc:black -fill white -draw 'point 5,4' image2.png
```

[image: image2]

To composite them in the way you describe, you would use `-compose` with `SCREEN` options.

```
composite -compose SCREEN image1.png image2.png result.png
```

[image: result]

Comment: This is a good solution. But I would recommend always using convert ... -composite rather than the old composite. Convert is more flexible, though in this case, composite is fine. `convert image1.png image2.png -compose screen -composite result.png`. You can also use -compose plus in place of screen.